# Argo giving x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs error

Tags: argoproj

I've installed Argo on a managed k8 service following the guidelines [here](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/installation/).

When i launch the following [example](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/examples/#hello-world) task i get an error (if you have argo installed you should be able to copy paster the below code):

```sh
# create a.yml
cat >> a.yml<<EOL
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: hello-world-  # Name of this Workflow
spec:
  entrypoint: whalesay        # Defines "whalesay" as the "main" template
  templates:
  - name: whalesay            # Defining the "whalesay" template
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay
      command: [cowsay]
      args: ["hello world"]   # This template runs "cowsay" in the "whalesay" image with arguments "hello world"

EOL

# submit a.yml
argo --insecure-skip-tls-verify --insecure-skip-verify -n argo submit a.yml

# monitor
$ argo list
# NAME                         STATUS      AGE   DURATION   PRIORITY
# hello-world-hxrcp            Succeeded   4m    10s        0

 argo watch --insecure-skip-tls-verify --insecure-skip-verify -v -n argo hello-world-hxrcp
# DEBU[2021-06-09T19:37:22.125Z] CLI version                                   version="{v3.0.7 2021-05-25T18:57:09Z e79e7ccda747fa4487bf889142c744457c26e9f7 v3.0.7 clean go1.16.3 gc linux/amd64}"
# DEBU[2021-06-09T19:37:22.125Z] Client options                                opts="(argoServerOpts=(url=127.0.0.1:2746,path=,secure=true,insecureSkipVerify=true,http=true),instanceID=)"
# DEBU[2021-06-09T19:37:22.125Z] curl -H 'Accept: text/event-stream' -H 'Authorization: ******' 'https://127.0.0.1:2746/api/v1/workflow-events/argo?listOptions.fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dhello-world-hxrcp&listOptions.resourceVersion=0' 
# FATA[2021-06-09T19:37:22.536Z] Get "https://127.0.0.1:2746/api/v1/workflow-events/argo?listOptions.fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dhello-world-hxrcp&listOptions.resourceVersion=0": x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

Why am i seeing this error ?

The install process was this:

```sh
kubectl create namespace argo
kubectl apply -n argo -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/stable/manifests/install.yaml
```

CLI ([taken from the latest version here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/tag/v3.0.7)):

```sh
# Download the binary
curl -sLO https://github.com/argoproj/argo/releases/download/v3.0.7/argo-linux-amd64.gz

# Unzip
gunzip argo-linux-amd64.gz

# Make binary executable
chmod +x argo-linux-amd64

# Move binary to path
sudo mv ./argo-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/argo

# Test installation
argo version

# link with server
# recommended on user panel in interface
cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOL
export ARGO_SERVER='127.0.0.1:2746' 
export ARGO_HTTP1=true  
export ARGO_SECURE=true
export ARGO_BASE_HREF=
export ARGO_TOKEN='' 
export ARGO_NAMESPACE=argo
export ARGO_INSECURE_SKIP_VERIFY=true
EOL

# check it works: 
argo list
```

Comment: Same issue here on a TKGI installation. I've deployed Argo in one cluster fine, but the second cluster failed with `Failed to register watch for controller config map: Get "https://10.100.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/argo-workflows-tst-workflow-controller-configmap": x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.100.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs`

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, I ran into this issue when setting up with the argo helm chart on kind.  The problem is that you have to disable tls verification for the executor (the thing that executes the workflow) using the `ARGO_KUBELET_INSECURE` env var.  Here are the docs https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/environment-variables/#executor

Sorry I don't have the exact code change you need for your setup, but I'm sure you can figure that out now that you know what the problem is ;).

Here's what my helm values.yaml file looks like in case that helps anyone else:

```
server:
  serviceType: LoadBalancer
  extraArgs:
  - --auth-mode=server

controller:
  containerRuntimeExecutor: k8sapi
executor:
  env:
  - name: ARGO_KUBELET_INSECURE
    value: true
```